# Blender Cycles Render solid black, but works fine in preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

At some moment my scene just stopped rendering, and now produces just a black(blue) solid screen after press <kbd>F12</kbd>. Blender version 2.9, tried in 2.8 as well, nothing works.

A couple of days ago all was fine, but then somthing has changed and I have been struggling to find a reason. The scene is quite complicated, got compositing for bloom effect.

I have tried to switch off compositing, gives no effect, all materials on preview look good.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe keep only one object of your scene and share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It is strange, I deleted all objects , created a cube and it works fine... Never heard of smth similar. Looks like there is smth with my render settings or some objects.. Tried to create new cameras and it still does not work